# Trying to remove extra space when using a tablet size screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just finished another front end website. I learned how to access the twitch api this time and I learned a lot. But I am still struggling with how bootstrap works. I figure the problem is has to do with how I am using the grid system.

The site looks great on a medium size screen and large screen. It even works well on phone size screens. But a tablet size, there is a lot of white space on the left side of the application(purple space), I can't figure out how to fix it, any tips? Thanks! http://codepen.io/freefora11/full/GodeRM/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="twitch">
    <h1 class="text-center"> Twitch API App</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1 buttons">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 show">
      <p>All</p>
      <p style="color:#A2FE1F">Online</p>
      <p style="color:#DA2E3E">Offline</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 but">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="all">show</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="on">show</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id="off">show</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content col-md-3 col-xs-1">

  </div>


</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your site is not responsive on the link you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the entire grid structure you used here is incorrect. I have provided the correct structure below before which I will give some tips to make it better.

1) It is always advised to wrap all the `.col-` classes inside `class="row"`.

2) In `.col-md-x`, the addition of the x values for a particular device(lg/md/sm/xs) should be 12 by default. In your case the outer `.col-md-` is adding upto only 6. `class="col-md-3" + class="col-md-3"`. I have provided the updated structure below.

3) Remove the `col-md-offset-1` and `col-xs-offset-1`.

4) Remove the `margin-left: 200px;` from the class `buttons` in your styles.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="twitch">
    <h1 class="text-center"> Twitch API App</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-3 buttons">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 show">
      <p>All</p>
      <p style="color:#A2FE1F">Online</p>
      <p style="color:#DA2E3E">Offline</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 but">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="all">show</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="on">show</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id="off">show</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
     <!--The details content comes here-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note this is made responsive only till the tablet/small devices as you wanted. For mobile devices you need to add and adjust all the `-xs-` classes the way you want.

Comment: thanks for the tip on making sure all my classes with the grid system should be using 'rows.'I didn't know they always had to add up to 12 as well. I completely forgot I put the margin for the buttons 200px, thats what was causing the biggest problem the whole time.

Comment: Awesome...If your problem is solved you could accept and close this question. Or you can ask if you have anything else.